# Problems with file reading in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I just begin learning COBOL and I want read file Dane.txt. I use Microsoft COBOL Compiler Version 2.20 in Win7 (Instruction how to install this compiler was the first what I found). This is my code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. RAPORT.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
SELECT IN-FILE ASSIGN TO DISK
    ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.

DATA DIVISION.

FILE SECTION.

FD IN-FILE
    DATA RECORD is INPUT-RECORD
LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
    VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "C:\MYCOBOL\COBOL\Dane.TXT".
01 INPUT-REC.
    05 ID-C PIC 9(5).
    05 Name         PIC X(15).
    05 ADDRESS      PIC X(8).
    05 NIP          PIC 9(10).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 SWITCHES.
    05 EOF-SWITCH   PIC X VALUE "N".

01 COUNTERS.
    05 REC-COUNTER  PIC 9(3) VALUE 0.


PROCEDURE DIVISION.
000-MAIN.

    PERFORM 100-INITIALIZE.
    PERFORM 200-PROCESS-RECORDS
        UNTIL EOF-SWITCH = "Y".
    PERFORM 300-TERMINATE.
    STOP RUN.

100-INITIALIZE.


    OPEN INPUT IN-FILE.

    READ IN-FILE
        AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
    END-READ.

200-PROCESS-RECORDS.

    DISPLAY "ID    --> " ID-C.
    DISPLAY "NAME  --> " NAME.
    DISPLAY "ADDRESS --> " ADDRESS.
    DISPLAY "NIP   --> " NIP.

    READ IN-FILE
        AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH
    END-READ.

300-TERMINATE.
    DISPLAY "THE END".
    CLOSE IN-FILE.
```

I get from my compiler message that END-READ is unrecognizable element and it is ignored. I have no idea what to do next. I do research but I found nothing. Maybe is another way to read file?

Comment: I try doing this. Without END-READ Procedure Division compile without problems, but after running program I get Run-Time Error in line where OPEN INPUT IN-FILE. are. In manual I find that END-READ is added to the standard.

Comment: Your code looks correct.  Without seeing the compiler output listing, it's hard to tell what is the problem.

Comment: [link]https://zapodaj.net/21641cfa35abf.png.html in this link is output of the compiler

Comment: @sebac13 Try changing the identifiers SWITCHES and ADDRESS to a different name.  INPUT-RECORD needs to match INPUT-REC as well. It looks like you are bumping into reserved words, and that causes a cascade effect on the compile pass.  Try and get rid of those first two warnings so that EOF-SWITCH is valid, then it should recognize the END-READ.

Comment: "COBOL compiler 2.2" The information about the version is misleading - What COBOL compiler do you use?
Depending on the compiler used `END-READ` may be not available (in this case removing it as Gilbert suggested in his answer is the fix).

BTW: If you don't need to use the old MS compiler I suggest to use [GnuCOBOL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/gnu-cobol/info).

Comment: full name is: Microsoft COBOL Compiler Version 2.20. Instruction how to instal this compiler was the first what I found, that is why I use that. I consider using GnuCOBOL, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your compilation has 4 syntax errors.

[image: Compilation Errors]

You have the following:

```
FD  IN-FILE
    DATA RECORD IS INPUT-RECORD
    LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
    VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "C:\MYCOBOL\COBOL\Dane.TXT".
01  INPUT-REC.
    05 ID-C         PIC 9(5).
    05 NAME         PIC X(15).
    05 ADDRESS      PIC X(8).
    05 NIP          PIC 9(10).
```

In one place, you say INPUT-RECORD.  When you define the record, you call it INPUT-REC.  Fix one or the other.

I don't see what's wrong with SWITCHES.  It might be a COBOL reserved word, so change it to WS-SWITCHES.

Finally, remove the END-READ from the two READ statements.  I suggest putting the READ statement in its own paragraph, and performing it as the priming read and the loop read.

Answer (score 0):

```
READ IN-FILE
        AT END
            MOVE "Y" TO EOF-SWITCH.
```

Cobol-74, end the read-statement with a period, not with `END-READ` (cobol-85)